# Google IoT with Xively API availability

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, xively

Google acquired Xively to integrate its IoT platform with Google IoT.

I would like to know, when will Google release the new APIs so that we can use the Xively API as part of accessing Google IoT core?

Answer (score 1):

There is a comment provided in the [Google Cloud Pub/Sub Discussions Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-pubsub-discuss/iqF5toD5BGo):

It is too soon to expect estimates on the API you would like to see implemented. I assume that a proper announcement will be offered to the press in due course. As you know, work on any piece of software takes time. The IoT market has its own dynamics and influences development priorities.